# MVC page requires password

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have been running my MVC.NET 5 project fine on my local dev PC. I've now published the site to the server but when I try to access any View of a specific controller, I am asked to sign in to something. The code doesn't require this functionality. The Controller is showing

```
    public ActionResult Failed()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

And my web.config is

```
 <system.web>
    <authentication mode="None" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" />
  </system.web>
```

I tested different browsers on different computers, the same issue persists.

When I visit `www.mysite.com/Home/SomeView` all works fine. When I visit `www.mysite.com/Report/View` or `www.mysite.com/Report/OtherView` (the Controller is called Report) I see the following

[image]

I don't have any authentication on my site (there is no login).

Why does the browser/website want me to log in when the site is published, but works as expected in my local environment.

Comment: can you please check , on those specific controllers where log in is prompted are they being differently handled  like missing of [AllowAnonymous] attribute

Comment: @kishoreVM how do I check this

Comment: On controller.cs or vb files before the actionresult methods do they have attributes like this text  [AllowAnonymous] on properlyworking and not properly working are differently put

Comment: No, there are no attributes of any kind, what you see is exactly as they are @kishoreVM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't find the reason why this works, but I simply renamed my Controller from Reports to Shares and it now works as desired.

My guess is probably having an incorrectly setup Route (such as a typo or similar).